# Complex matrix calculations

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Sorry about the vague subject but I really found some difficulties in calculating complex matrices.

Assume $Z$ is a square Hermitian non-singular complex matrix, then we denote
$$F=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
   Re(Z)  & -Im(Z) \\
   Im(Z)  & Re(Z)  \\
  \end{array}
\right], \tag{1}$$
where $Re(\cdot)$ and $Im(\cdot)$ represent the real part and imaginary part.
In a paper, it shows that the inverse of $F$ is given by
$$F^{-1}=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
   Re(Z^{-1})  & -Im(Z^{-1}) \\
   Im(Z^{-1})  & Re(Z^{-1})  \\
  \end{array}
\right]. \tag{2}$$
**My question 1: How to prove (2)?**

Another derivation in that paper, assume $Y$ also square complex matrix, then 
$$\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
   Re(Z^{-1})  & -Im(Z^{-1}) \\
   Im(Z^{-1})  & Re(Z^{-1})  \\
  \end{array}
\right] \left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    -Im(Y) \\
    Re(Y) \\
  \end{array}
\right] =  \left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    -Im(Z^{-1}Y) \\
    Re(Z^{-1}Y) \\
  \end{array}
\right]  \tag{3} $$
**My question 2: How to prove (3)?**

**Basically, as you can see, I have no idea how to calculate those $Re()$ and $Im()$. Do you have any idea how to search references about this subject? I searched "complex matrix computation", "real representation of complex matrices", no go. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem** 
$$
\begin{align}
Re(AB) &= Re(A)Re(B) -Im(A)Im(B) \\
Im(AB) &= Re(A)Im(B) + Im(A)Re(B)
\end{align}
$$

*Proof*
$$
\begin{align}
AB &= (Re(A)+iIm(A))(Re(B)+iIm(B)) \\
&= Re(A)Re(B) + i(Re(A)Im(B) + Im(A)Re(B)) - Im(A)Im(B).
\end{align}
$$
From which immediately follows that:
$$
\begin{align}
Re(AB) &= Re(A)Re(B) - Im(A)Im(B) \\
Im(AB) &= Re(A)Im(B) + Im(A)Re(B).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks. It perfectly answers my question 2. Any idea of proving question 1? Many thanks.

Comment: This answer all the questions. Think how. Hint: $Re(Id)= Id$ and $Im(Id)=0$.

Comment: @MIMIGA If you think this answered your question, please click the checkmark on the left hand side of the answer to mark it as the *right answer*.